# How come threads get created in my xcode project without me creating them explicitly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multithreading

I have been trying to understand how threads work in ios project. Whenever i set breakpoints and run my project in xcode, it shows me 4-5 threads running which i have no idea as to how and when did i create? I am posting this image of my xcode project showing the various threads running.

[image]

Can someone please help me with the 
1. understanding of threads in the above context
2. some good tutorial on thread creation and management.

Thanks a lot

Comment: All you need to know about thread on iOS is: you should put your GUI stuff logic into thread 1. You should not care about threads that are not yours. There's lot of way to manage thread: GCD (libDispatch - this is a queue manager), NSOperation, performSelectorOnBackgroung, posix thread, etc...

Comment: Thanks Mr Bonjour! :) That clears some blockage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger shows you all the threads running in the simulator. Even if you are not starting them explicitly, there are always some system threads and your application have several threads, e.g. the main thread is handling the UI but there is another one handling internet connections.

In summary, even a "Hello world" application will show you several threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sulthan. But can you suggest me a good article or some example which could help me understand the creation of threads. I have already been through some but not got the gist of it.